# Retrieve the "Service name" of a network card in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible under powershell to retrieve the "Service name" of the network card with PowerShell? Usually for Windows 10 it is rt640x64 and this name can be found in System information -> Components -> Network -> Card

Only I don't see how to retrieve this name with PowerShell, I can only retrieve the information with 'Get-NetAdapter' but it doesn't tell me the "Service name".

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Win32_NetworkAdapter` CIM class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) instances will have a corresponding `ServiceName` property:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter |Select Name,ServiceName
```

I only have one Realtek (USB) controller installed on my laptop, but I get the service name in the format you seem to expect:

```
Name                                      ServiceName
----                                      -----------
Realtek USB GbE Family Controller         rtux64w10
```

Comment: Indeed this is the format I expected. I find a similar result on my PC.
Thank you for the help